# How to match string based string on text file

Tags: php, string

Simply in php we could replace a string by other string such as using a particular function, str_replace (), etc

Suppose I have a `file.txt` contains

```
text1
text2
text3
...
text n
```

and i have a variable `$text` like

```
$text = "I want to get text1 and text2";
```

How to get the strings (`text1` and `text2`) based on the available strings in file.txt?

I want to have a new variable say ($new) which contains strings of $text that it fits on the string file.txt

So i have `$new="text1 text2";`

I still confused, how to adjust two text.

Any help wouldbe appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I would get contents from file into array, explode text at space and loop and compare both arrays. If there's a match push it to a new array. Finally implode the result with spaces to get your final string.

Comment: Your question is a bit complicated, do you want to know, how to find text1 and text2 in a file?

Comment: using file() to read textfile, and do some processing here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$fileTokens = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('file.txt'));
$textTokens = explode(' ', "I want to get text1 and text2");

$results = array_intersect($fileTokens, $textTokens);
var_dump($results);
```

To get the results as a space-delimited string, use this line

```
$stringResults = implode(' ', $results);
var_dump($stringResults);
```

Comment: congrats on reaching 3k :)